# Subsetting a dataframe on columns with ids from another dataframe

Tags: r, subset

I need to subset a dataframe on the columns with the ids given in another file.
How can I do that?
I have tried:

```
data_from_many_cells <- read.table("data_from_many_cells.txt", header=T)`
special_cells <- read.table("special_cells.txt", header=T)
data_from_special_cells <- data_from_many_cells[,special_cells]
```

But I get an error:

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: likely a duplicate but no in any case no one can help you unless you post your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

When we use `read.table` to read a `txt` file (assuming that the elements are in a single column in the `.txt` file, it will be read as `data.frame` with a single column (for the 'special_cells' dataset).  We can extract the column to a `vector` by numeric indexing (`[,1]`) or by the column name ( i.e. `special_cells[, 'yourcolumnname']`).  As we haven't provided the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument in `read.table`, if the column is non-numeric, it will be read as `factor`.  We can convert it to `character` and then use it for subsetting the 'data_from_many_cells'.

```
 data_from_many_cells[,as.character(special_cells[,1])]
```

Comment: @newa123 Can you update your post with `str(special_cells)` and `str(data_from_many_cells)`

Comment: I finally managed to subset only the desired cells. Thank you. I just had to remove as.character because the factor was actually a string factor